# Calculate the percentage of values in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array `$browser`:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Internet Explorer
            [1] => 5809
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Chrome
            [1] => 9205
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Safari
            [1] => 5288
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Opera
            [1] => 102
        )
```

Is there a way to calculate for each element the percentage . I tried this funtcion:

```
foreach ($browser as $key => $value){
print_array(array_avg($browser[$key][1]) );
    }

function array_avg($array, $round=1){
$num = count($array);
return array_map(
    function($val) use ($num,$round){
        return array('count'=>$val,'avg'=>round($val/$num*100, $round));
    },
    array_count_values($array));
}
```

Is there an error in my code?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do ?

Comment: Calculate the sum of all numbers for the total. Calculate the percentage as *total / 100 \* number*.

Comment: I want to replace for each element it percentage. For example, for `Internet Explorer` I'd like `5809` to be `65.51%` "for example" and so on.

Comment: Iterate over each element, find the total of all the arrays values combined together ($total) then ($value * 100) / $total

Comment: At first glance I can say that `print_array` is nothing, probably you want to use `print_r` instead !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// calculate the sum; first transform the array in something with only integers, then sum that array
$sum = array_sum(array_map(function ($a) { return $a[1]; }, $browser));

// walk through the array, print the percentage (value / sum) for each browser
foreach ($browser as $info) {
    echo 'Percentage for browser '.$info[0].' = '.round(($info[1]/$sum)*100).'%<br>';
}
```